# How to call an Objective C method in Swift that also has multiple arguments

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols, var, migrate

How exactly do I call an Objective c message with multiple protocols in swift? This is after I get up all of my bridged headers ect.

Objc message:

```
 NSString *TheDeviceId = [[[[MyLocationService instance] getTheDeviceType] getUserID] getUserValue];
```

Swift message:

```
var TheDeviceId = MyLocationService.instance (getTheDeviceType: AnyObject ,getUserID: AnyObject , getUserValue: AnyObject)
```

Comment: It does not have multiple protocols It consists of several methods that each take no parameter and act on the object returned by another function call

Answer (score 4):

That's not a single message with multiple arguments. It's a series of <strike>tubes</strike> chained messages -- each additional method call made against the return value of the previous call. Your ObjC is equivalent to (with a guess at some intermediate class names):

```
MyLocationService *service = [MyLocationService instance];
MyDeviceType *theType = [service getTheDeviceType];
MyUserID *userID = [theType getUserID];
NSString *theDeviceID = [userID getUserValue];
```

Once you see that, it's pretty simple to do the same in Swift:

```
let service = MyLocationService.instance()
let theType = service.getTheDeviceType()
let userID = theType.getUserID()
let theDeviceID = userID.getUserValue()
```

And then string it back together for brevity:

```
MyLocationService.instance().getTheDeviceType().getUserID().getUserValue()
```

Comment: And possibly needing some optional chaining if the methods can return nil.

Answer (score 1):

Those are multiple calls to multiple methods, you have to call each one individually. You should just be able to chain them together.

```
MyLocationService.instance().getTheDeviceType().getUserID().getUserValue()
```

Each method is called on the return value of the method called immediately before.